# update a column in my table by using procedure

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
   ENO        NUMBER (3),
   ENAME      VARCHAR2 (35),
   HIREDATE   DATE,
   SAL        NUMBER (6),
   EXPR       NUMBER (3),
   DEPTNO     NUMBER (3),
   JOB        VARCHAR2 (20),
   COMM       NUMBER (10)
)
```

,this is my table structure,i that "COMM" column doesn't having any values,i want to add the values based on the "SAL" column by using procedure,write a procedure to add the values

Comment: Should we write your homework?

Comment: i am trying to do it from 2 days

Comment: send me some clues i'll do it

Comment: Naveen, this homework is 100 times done here. Use the search box

Comment: Read first here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/overview.htm and than if you cannot do it come back. You should read your lection and course material, before to do something

Comment: Hint: Write a cursor for your employees table. Then yse a record to loop through all rows. When you are looping through the rows you can do an update statement on the column COMM.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XX_UPDATETBEMP
AS
   PROCEDURE  XX_UPDATECOMM;
END XX_UPDATETBEMP;



CREATE or REPLACE  PACKAGE BODY XX_UPDATETBEMP

IS
   PROCEDURE   XX_UPDATECOMM
   IS
   BEGIN
      UPDATE emp
         SET comm =
                CASE
                   WHEN sal BETWEEN 30000 AND 50000 THEN .20 * sal
                   WHEN sal BETWEEN 50000 AND 70000 THEN .15 * sal
       WHEN sal BETWEEN 70000 AND 100000 THEN .10 * sal
                END;
   END XX_UPDATECOMM;
END XX_UPDATETBEMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE XX_UDCOMMS IS
    CURSOR C_TBEMP IS
      SELECT * FROM XX_TBEMP;
    l_comm NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    FOR C IN C_TBEMP LOOP
      l_comm := NULL;

      IF C.SAL BETWEEN 30000 AND 49999 THEN
        l_comm := c.sal * 0.2;
      ELSIF C.SAL BETWEEN 50000 AND 79999 THEN
        l_comm := c.sal * 0.15;
      ELSIF C.SAL BETWEEN 80000 AND 99999 THEN
        l_comm := c.sal * 0.1;
      END IF;

      UPDATE XX_TBEMP SET COMM = l_comm WHERE c.eno = eno;
    END LOOP;
  end;
```